# How to prevent triggers from cutting off so much of the text field?

Tags: extjs, extjs6, extjs6-classic

As an example, this is code which provides a clear trigger for one text field, and not for the other, as a comparison:

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    title: 'Contact Info',
    width: 300,
    bodyPadding: 10,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    items: [{
        xtype: 'textfield',
        name: 'fname',
        fieldLabel: 'First Name',
        triggers: {
            clear: {
                cls: 'fa fa-times',
                handler: function(me) {
                    me.setValue('');
                }
            }
        }
    },{
        xtype: 'textfield',
        name: 'lname',
        fieldLabel: 'Last Name'
    }]
});
```

When you run it, the clear trigger is way in the middle of the field, and physically reduces its width. (I typed Xs to demo.)

[image: screen shot of code running, entered a lot of Xs]

I'd like the trigger much farther to the right, with the text field expanded accordingly. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `x-fa class` instead of `fa` (`cls: 'x-fa fa-times'`)

Comment: Yep, that did it!